# Links to book series on Amazon are being mangled

Tags: bug

I answered a question and included a link to a book series on Amazon,

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00YSGMWQ2
```

The link worked in the preview, but when the answer was posted it had been replaced with

```
http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YSGMWQ2
```

which redirects to

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00YSGMWQ2/?tag=stackoverfl08-20
```

which shows a "page not found".  I tried again and the same thing happened.  What's going on here?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: I suspect that this is a problem on Amazon's side.

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect this would get more attention and a faster resolution on the main meta.

Comment: The redirection is part of Stack's policy of gleaning revenue from posted Amazon links. Not sure why it's ballsed-up though.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a ([replicatable](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11065/revisions)) bug, relating to the [auto-insertion of Amazon links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) by Stack Exchange.

---

Until it's fixed, there's a simple workaround. Use a URL shortening service (like [**TinyURL**](https://tinyurl.com/) or [**goo.gl**](https://goo.gl/)) to create a new link with the same end point. Stack Exchange doesn't recognise this as an Amazon link and hence doesn't muck it up.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00YSGMWQ2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YSGMWQ2) **>** https://tinyurl.com/ycfrgsk9